# mod_rewrite - Change Folder to Filename

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, synology

I'm searching for a RewriteRule or Condition to make this happen:

```
www.example.com/a/ to a.php
www.example.com/a/b/ to a,b.php
www.example.com/a/b/c/ to a,b,c.php
...
```

I had this Rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/$ ./$1,$2,$3.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/$ ./$1,$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ ./$1.php [L]
```

That worked for `a,b` and `a,b,c`:

```
www.example.com/products/room/ to products,room.php
www.example.com/products/room/chair/ to products,room,chair.php
```

but not for `a`:

```
www.example.com/products/ to products.php
```

Can anyone help me out?

EDIT:
*I figured out that this is a problem with the synology diskstation apache configuration.
I checked my code, and the code of anubhava on another server and it worked fine.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very strange filenames I must say that.

Anyway try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f    
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1,$2.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1,$2,$3.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but thats not working for me

Comment: now the first one (..com/a/ to a.php) is working but (a,b.php and a,b,c.php) are not working

Comment: ok one more edit, try it now.

Comment: still working for (a.php) but not for (a,b.php and a,b,c.php). And thats my weird problem because there works only (a) or (ab + abc) but not all together

Comment: Is the only code in .htaccess OR you have more code?

Comment: ok i checked your code on another server and it works, but on my home synology ds (apache) that code fails

Comment: Yes I have tested this code myself and it worked fine too on my server.

Comment: thanks for your great help, now i'll try to locate the problem on my homeserver

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be of any help.